# double implication proof

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

How would I go about said proof: I know how to do it with just a single logical equivalence, but how would I prove a double implication?
[image: problem77984297934]

Comment: You can just replace $\iff$ by $\implies$ in your proof to get the *only if* direction. Similarly for the other direction.

Comment: "$\Rightarrow$" would be assume $x$ and $y$ rational. Then prove their product is rational.
"$\Leftarrow$" would be assume $xy$ rational. Then prove $x$ and $y$ are both rational.
Hint: The "$\Leftarrow$" implication is false.

Comment: There are two things to prove, each involving a single implication. But note that the double implication is not true. If $x$ and $y$ are rational, then $xy$ is rational. But if $xy$ is rational, it is not necessarily the case that $x$ and $y$ are rational.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac{m}{n}+\frac{p}{q}=\frac{m+p}{nq}.$$